# How to turn off bluetooth in MATE?

Tags: bluetooth, 18.04, mate

In MATE bluetooth seems to be controlled with `Bluetooth Adapters` and `Bluetooth Manager` in the control center. However Bluetooth Adapters only allows to control visibility, but not to turn bluetooth off and Bluetooth Manager lists available services and manages connections.

I'm aware that I can turn off bluetooth with `sudo systemctl stop bluetooth`, but there has to be a way provided by the desktop.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blueman has the `blueman-applet` tray icon, it is located inside
 *Indicator Applet Complete* (`mate-indicator-applet` package) - see image

[image: Bluetooth tray icon on MATE]

It changes

```
$ rfkill list all
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

to

```
$ rfkill list all
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

and vise versa.

Comment: I don't see why this shouldn't work and thus mark it as correct, however I don't have a possibility to test this since the `blueman-applet` tray icon is only displayed for a second and the disappears without any obvious issues printed to console (the log output doesn't seem to be very thoughtful anyway which is why I suggested https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman/issues/874 btw).